# OpenCV memory leak issue

Tags: memory-leaks, opencv, c++-cli

This function of drawItem is called multiple times through a loop, I'm facing a memory leak issue everytime it is called. I'm thinking that the problem is due to the resizeImage() function, but I can't seem to pinpoint the problem, this is C++\CLI with OpenCV library.

```
drawItem()
{
imgItem = resizeImage(imgItem, newItemWidth, newItemHeight, false);
imgMask = resizeImage(imgMask, newItemWidth, newItemHeight, false);
cvSetImageROI(image3, cvRect(x1,y1,newItemWidth, newItemHeight));
cvCopy(imgItem, image3, imgMask);
cvResetImageROI(image3);
cvReleaseImage( &imgItem );
cvReleaseImage( &imgMask );
}

IplImage* resizeImage(const IplImage *origImg, int newWidth, int newHeight, bool keepAspectRatio)
{
    IplImage *outImg = 0;
    int origWidth;
    int origHeight;
    if (origImg) {
        origWidth = origImg->width;
        origHeight = origImg->height;
    }
    if (newWidth <= 0 || newHeight <= 0 || origImg == 0
        || origWidth <= 0 || origHeight <= 0) {
        //cerr << "ERROR: Bad desired image size of " << newWidth
        //  << "x" << newHeight << " in resizeImage().\n";
        exit(1);
    }

    if (keepAspectRatio) {
        // Resize the image without changing its aspect ratio,
        // by cropping off the edges and enlarging the middle section.
        CvRect r;
        // input aspect ratio
        float origAspect = (origWidth / (float)origHeight);
        // output aspect ratio
        float newAspect = (newWidth / (float)newHeight);
        // crop width to be origHeight * newAspect
        if (origAspect > newAspect) {
            int tw = (origHeight * newWidth) / newHeight;
            r = cvRect((origWidth - tw)/2, 0, tw, origHeight);
        }
        else {  // crop height to be origWidth / newAspect
            int th = (origWidth * newHeight) / newWidth;
            r = cvRect(0, (origHeight - th)/2, origWidth, th);
        }
        IplImage *croppedImg = cropImage(origImg, r);

        // Call this function again, with the new aspect ratio image.
        // Will do a scaled image resize with the correct aspect ratio.
        outImg = resizeImage(croppedImg, newWidth, newHeight, false);
        cvReleaseImage( &croppedImg );

    }
    else {

        // Scale the image to the new dimensions,
        // even if the aspect ratio will be changed.
        outImg = cvCreateImage(cvSize(newWidth, newHeight),
            origImg->depth, origImg->nChannels);
        if (newWidth > origImg->width && newHeight > origImg->height) {
            // Make the image larger
            cvResetImageROI((IplImage*)origImg);
            // CV_INTER_LINEAR: good at enlarging.
            // CV_INTER_CUBIC: good at enlarging.           
            cvResize(origImg, outImg, CV_INTER_LINEAR);
        }
        else {
            // Make the image smaller
            cvResetImageROI((IplImage*)origImg);
            // CV_INTER_AREA: good at shrinking (decimation) only.
            cvResize(origImg, outImg, CV_INTER_AREA);
        }

    }
    return outImg;
}

IplImage* cropImage(const IplImage *img, const CvRect region)
{
    IplImage *imageCropped;
    CvSize size;

    if (img->width <= 0 || img->height <= 0
        || region.width <= 0 || region.height <= 0) {
        //cerr << "ERROR in cropImage(): invalid dimensions." << endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    if (img->depth != IPL_DEPTH_8U) {
        //cerr << "ERROR in cropImage(): image depth is not 8." << endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    // Set the desired region of interest.
    cvSetImageROI((IplImage*)img, region);
    // Copy region of interest into a new iplImage and return it.
    size.width = region.width;
    size.height = region.height;
    imageCropped = cvCreateImage(size, IPL_DEPTH_8U, img->nChannels);
    cvCopy(img, imageCropped);  // Copy just the region.

    return imageCropped;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found out the problem, it is due to Multiple Memory Allocations.

imgItem was pointing to something earlier, but after i did 
imgItem = resizeImage(imgItem, newItemWidth, newItemHeight, false);

imgItem now points to another thing, the memory created in when imgItem was created is lost forever, no variable points to it, hence a memory leak.

so i used tempImgItem to solve the problem,

```
tempImgItem = resizeImage(imgItem, newItemWidth, newItemHeight, false);
tempImgMask = resizeImage(imgMask, newItemWidth, newItemHeight, false);
cvReleaseImage( &imgItem );
cvReleaseImage( &imgMask );
imgItem = tempImgItem;
imgMask = tempImgMask;
tempImgItem = NULL;
tempImgMask = NULL;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it is because you call "resizeImage" in itself, and you forgot to release the outImage inside

Comment: I tried putting a cvReleaseImage( &imgItem ); after the IplImage *outImg = 0; but it is still leaking memory :/

Comment: i mean (&outImg). also i cant put cvReleaseImage(&outImg) right before return, the program will crash

Comment: i believe you are right in that I have to release the outImg, because i created it with cvCreateImage, it must be released. But the problem now is how do I release it because I need to "return" it :/

Comment: I suggest:

1. the image for output should be declared outside the function, then pass into by reference parameter. Creating image inside the function then return it out often cause some problem.

2. you use iteration (function call itself) for looping operation, maybe you can change to for/while loop type, this way will make memory usage more clear