# Huge memory leak in opencv

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, memory-leaks, ubuntu-12.04

I've written a very very simple C++ program to read 600 video frames in a multi-threaded code. the problem is that when I release each of these frames the free memory size doesn't change!
I'm using qt 4.8 and ubuntu 12.04
My Laptop Memory size is 8 GB so I don't have any memory shortage.

each frame is 1.8 MB so the total size is 600*1.8 MB =  1080 MB

before running the program my memory free size is 6.8 GB but after running my code and letting it to finish I see the free memory size is 5.9 GB so I see there's a huge memory leak in the program. I've run my code 1000 times and never saw my program crashes or face any problems so the code is okay.

My code:

```
#include "im_loader.h"

IM_Loader::IM_Loader(QObject *parent) :
    QThread(parent)
{
}


void IM_Loader::run()
{
    QString PATH = "/home/parsa/QtProjects/MonoSD/";
     {
     for(float i = 0 ; i < 1 ; i++)
       {
         QString Folder_Address = PATH + QString::number((int)i)+"/";
         QDir Mydir(Folder_Address);
         Mydir.setFilter(QDir::Files);
         QFileInfoList Vehicles_list = Mydir.entryInfoList();
         qDebug()<<"Address is: "<<Folder_Address<<"\n";
         qDebug()<<"Number of images are: "<<Vehicles_list.size()<<"\n";
         static int overall_counter = 0; //12451
         for(int j = 0 ; j < 600 ; j++)
           {
             if(!Stop_Disp)
             {
                QString address = Folder_Address + QString::number(overall_counter++) +".jpg";
                cv::Mat image = cv::imread(address.toUtf8().constData(),0);
                if(!image.data)
                {
                    qDebug()<<"Image Data is failed ... \n";
                    continue;
                }
                if(j%100==0)
                qDebug()<<"Folder "<<i<<" Image No. "<<j<<" is processed, Overall counter is: "<<overall_counter<<"\n";
                cv::Mat Dataaa;
                image.copyTo(Dataaa);
                QMutexLocker Locker(&Global_Mutex);
                PD_Classifier_VEC.push_back(Dataaa);
                Locker.unlock();
                }
            }
        }
     }
    qDebug("Im loader is exited now ...");
}
```

im_loader.h

```
#ifndef IM_LOADER_H
#define IM_LOADER_H


#include "Definitions.h"

class IM_Loader : public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit IM_Loader(QObject *parent = 0);
    void run();
    bool Stop_Disp;
signals:

public slots:

};

#endif // IM_LOADER_H
```

Mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
QTimer *Mytimer;
QMutex Global_Mutex;
IM_Loader IML;
std::vector<cv::Mat> PD_Classifier_VEC;
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    IML.start();
    Mytimer = new QTimer(this);
    Mytimer->singleShot(20000,this,SLOT(Clear_Vec()));
}

void MainWindow::Clear_Vec()
{
    qDebug()<<"PD_Classifier_VEC.SIZE IS: "<<PD_Classifier_VEC.size();
    for(int i = 0 ; i < PD_Classifier_VEC.size() ; i++)
    {
        QMutexLocker Locker(&Global_Mutex);
        PD_Classifier_VEC.erase(PD_Classifier_VEC.begin() + i);
        Locker.unlock();
        i--;
    }
   Mytimer->singleShot(10000,this,SLOT(Clear_Vec()));
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

Mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include "Definitions.h"

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();
    void Delay(int Milisecond_Delay);
public slots:
    void Clear_Vec();
private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

Definitions.h

```
#ifndef DEFINITIONS_H
#define DEFINITIONS_H
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QThread>
#include <QTimer>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QDir>
#include <QMutex>
#include <QMutexLocker>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include "im_loader.h"

extern std::vector<cv::Mat> PD_Classifier_VEC;
extern QMutex Global_Mutex;
#endif // DEFINITIONS_H
```

I've read in some articles that opencv c++ version support memory management so we don't have to be worry about memory leaks.

am I missing something here ? I've read these questions too but none of them worked for me
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18189934/opencv-cvmat-causing-potential-memory-leak-with-stdvector) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5610294/opencv-memory-leak-issue)

Just one post amused me is SO and made me think if I have this problem in my code but I couldn't figure out. [this is the link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16430373/what-is-causing-my-memory-leak-with-opencv)

I'll provide anything else if needed.

**EDITED:**

it's very interesting that if I add a Delay function in my imageloader class just after reading each frame the amount of memory leaks reduces !!!

My new im_loader.cpp

```
void IM_Loader::Delay(int Milisecond_Delay)
{
    double OneSecond = cv::getTickFrequency();
    int Milisecond = OneSecond/4000;

   for(double t1= 0 ; t1 < Milisecond_Delay ; t1++)
          for(double t2= 0 ; t2 < Milisecond; t2++);
}
void IM_Loader::run()
{
    QString PATH = "/home/parsa/QtProjects/FINAL_VLPR/LowSpeed/";//Dataset_PATH;
     //while(1)
     {
     for(float i = 0 ; i < 1 ; i++)
       {
         QString Folder_Address = PATH + QString::number((int)i)+"/";
         QDir Mydir(Folder_Address);
         Mydir.setFilter(QDir::Files);
         QFileInfoList Vehicles_list = Mydir.entryInfoList();
         qDebug()<<"Address is: "<<Folder_Address<<"\n";
         qDebug()<<"Number of images are: "<<Vehicles_list.size()<<"\n";
         static int overall_counter = 0; //12451
         for(int j = 0 ; j < 300 ; j++)
           {
             if(!Stop_Disp)
             {
                QString address = Folder_Address + QString::number(overall_counter++) +".jpg";
                cv::Mat image = cv::imread(address.toUtf8().constData(),0);
                Delay(100);
                if(!image.data)
                {
                    qDebug()<<"Image Data is failed ... \n";
                    continue;
                }
                if(j%100==0)
                qDebug()<<"Folder "<<i<<" Image No. "<<j<<" is processed, Overall counter is: "<<overall_counter<<"\n";
                cv::Mat Dataaa;
                image.copyTo(Dataaa);
                QMutexLocker Locker(&Global_Mutex);
                PD_Classifier_VEC.push_back(Dataaa);
                Locker.unlock();
                }
            }
        }
     }
    qDebug("Im loader is exited now ...");
}
```

adding a 100 ms delay reduced the memory leakage to only 100 Mega Bytes instead of 1 Gigabyte !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found out what caused this memory leak ... as you can see in the im_loader class and specifically run() function I have this block of code:

```
 cv::Mat Dataaa;
 image.copyTo(Dataaa);
 QMutexLocker Locker(&Global_Mutex);
 PD_Classifier_VEC.push_back(Dataaa);
 Locker.unlock();
```

Since OpenCV use a reference counting procedure for cv::Mat object, input image is copied into Dataa variable and then into PD_Classifier.  PD_Classifier gets deleted but Dataa no ! so when I removed this line and change the code to this the problem got solved:

```
  QMutexLocker Locker(&Global_Mutex);
  PD_Classifier_VEC.push_back(image);
  Locker.unlock();
```

I thought that since Dataa is a local variable it will be deleted after exiting the run() function but it appears that although it gets deleted after exiting the function its data stays on memory.

Comment: Next time use proper tools for memory analysis such as Valgrind, which btw is integrated into Qt Creator although I'm not sure how well so it might be good to also rely on the console. It also has the ability to analyze parallel programs, which is your case. I've used it in Eclipse and in console.

Comment: @rbaleksandar I've tested my code using valgrind but I got no result from it. Valgrind couldn't detect what's going on and I think it's because of the reference counting algorithm of OpenCV.